# Continuously redraw wxPython element

Tags: python, wxpython, refresh, timer

I have a chat client that continuously polls a server and fetches new messages.

From my **def __init__()** I have:

```
wx.CallAfter(self.pollServer)
```

Which is defined:

```
def pollServer(self):
    t = self.updateMessages()
    time.sleep(5)
    self.pollServer()
```

Now printing the messages into the Terminal shows that it works but the GUI is 'frozen' instead of being continuously refreshed and I thought CallAfter takes care of that. Could you help?

Comment: Just found out about wxPyTimer() is that the alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of

```
time.sleep(5)
self.pollServer()
```

try with

```
wx.CallLater(5,self.pollServer)
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CallLater'

Comment: ah ok, seems like in wx 2.8 its Renamed wx.FutureCall to wx.CallLater, so may be yours is wx.FutureCall 
http://www.wxpython.org/recentchanges.php